# blockui until not completed download file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, download, blockui

I'm creating a file on button click and send it to user to download it.

I'm using jQuery blockUi to display a message while this is executing.

I want to unblockUi until download executes

How can I do this?

I create file and send to user with handler at the end of create file i write a cookie and in the jquery i check the cookie,if cookie is not null then unblockUi :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
    function blockUIForDownload() {
        if (IsCookiesEnable()) {
            var token = new Date().getTime(); //use the current timestamp as the token value
            $('#download_token_value_id').val(token);

            $.blockUI({
                message:$('#msg'),
                css: {
                    padding: 0,
                    margin: 0,
                    width: '30%',
                    top: '40%',
                    left: '35%',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    color: '#000',
                    border: '3px solid #aaa',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    cursor: 'wait',
                }});


            fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
            var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
            //alert(cookieValue);
                if (cookieValue != null)
                   finishDownload();
            }, 1000);
               // $('.blockOverlay').attr('title','Click to unblock').click($.unblockUI);
        }
    }

    function IsCookiesEnable() {
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = "testcookie";
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
        }
        return (cookieEnabled);
    }

    function finishDownload() {
        window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
       $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null);
        $.unblockUI();

    }
```

and at code behind:

```
context.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", _token));
```

Comment: FYI, I've fixed it, after mucking around on this all day and finally posting on here. I ended up deleting the cookie with the command: $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null, { path: '/' });